# Bokeh plot conditional background color

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a pandas dataframe containing a boolean column like this:

```
| A | B |   C   |
| 1 | 3 | True  |
| 2 | 4 | True  |
| 3 | 4 | False |
| 4 | 1 | False |
| 5 | 2 | True  |
```

And I would like to plot the values of B on y and A on X with a conditional background color based on C
I mean something like this : [image: simulated result]

Can I do that with box annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using the `left` and `right` arguments of `BoxAnnotation`:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import BoxAnnotation

output_notebook()

# dummy data 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   "B": [3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3],
                   "C": [True, True, False, False, True, True]})
print(df)

>>>     A   B   C

    0   1   3   True
    1   2   4   True
    2   3   4   False
    3   4   1   False
    4   5   2   True
    5   6   3   True
```

For simplification, I add another row here to get even `True` counts for plotting.

Now, get the consecutive rows containing `True`:

```
df["cons"] = (df["C"].diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum() 
mask = df["cons"] % 2 == 1

cons_indices = df[mask].groupby("cons").apply(lambda x: x.A.values)
print(cons_indices)

>>> cons
    1    [1, 2]
    3    [5, 6]
    dtype: object
```

And finally plot it:

```
p = figure(title="Annotations")
p.line(df["A"], df["B"])

for cons_index in cons_indices:
    low_box = BoxAnnotation(left=cons_index.min(), right=cons_index.max(), fill_color="Blue")
    p.add_layout(low_box)

show(p)
```

The solution does not deal with single `True` (non consecutive `True`) values, yet. However, you haven't specified the appropriate behavior for this scenario.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works, had to adapt a bit because my real dataset have datetime index but it is ok now, thanks a lot